# Don't Display contact number in message

Tags: android, sqlite

```
            db=helper.getReadableDatabase();
            cursor=db.query(DBHelper.TABLE, new String[]{DBHelper.CONTACT_NO}, null, null, null, null, null);
            String listContact[]=fromCursorToStringArray(cursor);
            Log.d("Array",Arrays.toString(listContact));
            String sms = "This is custom message" + "\n" + "IMEI : " + mngr.getDeviceId() + "\n" + "Location : " + provider + "\n" + Arrays.toString(listContact) + contact_name;
            try 
            {
                android.telephony.SmsManager smsmanager = android.telephony.SmsManager.getDefault();

                for(int i=0; i<listContact.length; i++)
                {
                    smsmanager.sendTextMessage(listContact[i], null, sms, null, null);
                    Log.d("index", listContact[i]);
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"SMS faild, please try again later!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

When I seen in Log it is give me all contact number in array but while I am concat in string at that time contact number does not display in message

```
String sms = "This is custom message" + "\n" + "IMEI : " + mngr.getDeviceId() + "\n" + "Location : " + provider + "\n" + Arrays.toString(listContact) + contact_name;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because of the brackets.

I have created function for remove brackets will work. Its working my side

```
private String subString(String sms) 
{
    String temp = "";
    for(int i=1;i<(sms.length()-1);i++)
    {
        temp += sms.charAt(i);
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First you put your array to String Variable then after Concat with your message.
String temp=Arrays.toString(listContact);

String sms = "This is custom message" + "\n" + "IMEI : " + mngr.getDeviceId() + "\n" + "Location : " + provider + "\n" + temp + contact_name;

Some times Android cant directly Convert and concat operation simontenously.
Try it hope it will help you.

or

Second thing is check your Contactlist cherecter length becouse there are charecter limit in message. so if contactlist length exceed max allowed length it became media so check this scenario also.

Comment: have you check second thing?